# Add Windows 10 Boot loader with no efi found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Currently I have to manually hit delete and boot from my Bios to get this working.

My Windows 10 install is on `├─sdb4        8:20   0 445.3G  0 part /mnt/windows`

Sadly it does not come up with `sudo os-prober` either. Below is my lsblk

```
hutber@hutber:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8213
loop1         7:1    0  89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/8268
loop2         7:2    0  54.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/1650
loop3         7:3    0  54.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/1288
loop4         7:4    0 259.4M  1 loop /snap/acestreamplayer/9
loop5         7:5    0 259.4M  1 loop /snap/acestreamplayer/10
loop6         7:6    0   2.8M  1 loop /snap/pulseaudio/9
sdb           8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0   450M  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb3        8:19   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb4        8:20   0 445.3G  0 part /mnt/windows
├─sdb5        8:21   0   851M  0 part 
└─sdb6        8:22   0   450M  0 part 
sdc           8:32   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/xbox
sdd           8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sdd1        8:49   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdd2        8:50   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/tv
sde           8:64   0   7.3T  0 disk 
└─sde1        8:65   0   7.3T  0 part /mnt/googledrive
sdf           8:80   0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sdf1        8:81   0 222.5G  0 part /mnt/oldlinux
├─sdf2        8:82   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdf5        8:85   0    16G  0 part 
sdg           8:96   1   3.7T  0 disk 
├─sdg1        8:97   1   128M  0 part 
└─sdg2        8:98   1   3.7T  0 part /mnt/downloads
sdh           8:112  1   3.7T  0 disk 
└─sdh1        8:113  1   3.7T  0 part /mnt/jay
sdi           8:128  1   7.3T  0 disk 
├─sdi1        8:129  1   128M  0 part 
└─sdi2        8:130  1   7.3T  0 part /mnt/users
sdl           8:176  1  14.9G  0 disk 
└─sdl1        8:177  1  14.9G  0 part /media/hutber/72AD-2013
sr0          11:0    1   4.1G  0 rom  /media/hutber/MB Support CD1
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   450M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    99M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 247.4G  0 part /mnt/c
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  11.2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0    10M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0 672.4G  0 part /
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Sadly not, I do now have a windows boot option in my grub menu, but it does not boot correctly. `errors: invalid signature. Press any key to continue...`

Comment: Try the Rescatux answer.

Comment: Grub will not boot Windows is UEFI Secure Boot is on. Something about secure boot cannot be confirmed from one system to another. You can boot from UEFI boot menu if Secure Boot is on.